# Drupal menu_get_object error (The server closed the connection > without sending any data)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, module

I am using menu_get_object() in my module hook_nodeapi function. Due to that code I get the following error:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection
> without sending any data.

The code is as follows:

```
 function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4){    
    $nodex = menu_get_object();
    drupal_set_message("Currnet Node(test) : {$nodex->nid}");
 }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `$node` is passed in by reference to the `hook_nodeapi()` function and you're trying to re-assign it using `menu_get_object()`.

You should either use a different name for the second node you want to load, e.g.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4){    
  $other_node = menu_get_object();
  drupal_set_message("Currnet Node(test) : {$other_node->nid}");
}
```

Or, if you're looking for the node to which the `nodeapi` function is referring to, just use the `$node` object passed into the function.

**UPDATE**

I think this will do what you're trying to do:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4){ 
  // If this call to nodeapi is for the currently visited node page
  // $a3 contains a boolean indicating whether the view mode is teaser of full.
  if ($op == 'view' && !$a3) {
    drupal_set_message('Current Node : ' . $node->nid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The variable name was definitely an issue and I have corrected my code and the snippet above. But unfortunately, I still get the same error. The function is supposed to return the node currently being visited. When I try using $node from the arguments list, it prints multiple $node->nid's. They are all the nodes present on the page listed by views, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick. Can I bug you for an explanation please. It certainly was not clear to me what function $a3 and $a4 serve in the arguments list. I would really appreciate a short explanation. Thanks regardless!

Comment: At a guess: Functions internally called within `menu_get_object()` actually use `node_load` on the object again, which invokes `hook_nodeapi`, which then goes through your hook, which then calls `menu_get_object` again...I'd say that causes an infinite loop which Drupal won't be able to recover from. The [docs for `hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) have all the details for what is passed in in `$a3` and `$a4` for each particular `$op` :)

Comment: I wonder if you could help me out with a similar problem? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342169/drupal-hook-menu-alter-menu-get-object-error